# How to sign a generic text with RSA key and encode with Base64 in Java?

Tags: java, encryption, base64, rsa, sign

I have the following code in bash:

```
signed_request = $(printf "PLAIN TEXT REQUEST" | 
openssl rsautl -sign -inkey "keyfile.pem" | openssl enc -base64 | _chomp )
```

Basically, this code takes a plain text, signs it with a private key and encodes using Base64

How could I do a code with exactly the same functionality in Java?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [JDK security API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/index.html). Take a look at this working [sample](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/SimpleDigitalSignatureExample.htm), hope it can get you started:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(1024);
    KeyPair keyPair = kpg.genKeyPair();

    byte[] data = "test".getBytes("UTF8");

    Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("MD5WithRSA");
    sig.initSign(keyPair.getPrivate());
    sig.update(data);
    byte[] signatureBytes = sig.sign();
    System.out.println("Singature:" + new BASE64Encoder().encode(signatureBytes));

    sig.initVerify(keyPair.getPublic());
    sig.update(data);

    System.out.println(sig.verify(signatureBytes));
  }
```

EDIT: 
The example above uses internal Sun's encoder (`sun.misc.BASE64Encoder`). It is best to use something like [Base64](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) from `Commons Codec`.

Comment: Your code does not take a private key form a file (see the example in bash code).

Comment: Here is a [sample](http://codeartisan.blogspot.com/2009/05/public-key-cryptography-in-java.html) how to read keys. Make sure your key is in PKCS8 format.

Comment: Java 8 now comes with a decoder `java.util.Base64.getDecoder`

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can use [not-yet-commons-ssl](http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/pkcs8.html) to obtain the private key from a file and encode using `org.apache.commons.ssl.Base64`. Using Max's example:

```
import java.security.Signature;
import org.apache.commons.ssl.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.ssl.PKCS8Key;

// [...]

PKCS8Key pkcs8 = new PKCS8Key(new FileInputStream("keyfile.pem"),
                              "changeit".toCharArray());

Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("MD5WithRSA");
sig.initSign(pkcs8.getPrivateKey());
sig.update(data);
byte[] signatureBytes = sig.sign();

System.out.println("Singature: " +
                   Base64.encodeBase64String(signatureBytes));
```

Comment: `new PKCS8Key(new FileInputStream("keyfile.pem"), "changeit".toCharArray());`  this doesn't work at all. This method is protected and expects other arguments, incompatible with FileInputStream.

Comment: @VasyaNovikov I added the imports to clarify the code. It's `org.apache.commons.ssl.PKCS8Key`, I think you are trying to use `sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key`. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I copy the link @Aqua posted as a new answer, because I think it's FAR more useful than any of the answers given yet. Use THIS to read/write private/public keys from files:
http://codeartisan.blogspot.ru/2009/05/public-key-cryptography-in-java.html

The link doesn't say anythig about signing and verifying, but signing is a lot easier. I used this code to sign:

```
    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256WithRSA");
    signature.initSign(privateKey);

    signature.update("text to sign".getBytes());
    signature.sign();
```

And to verify:

```
    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256WithRSA");
    signature.initVerify(publicKey);
    signature.update("text to sign".getBytes);
    signature.verify(signatureMadeEarlier);
```