# Signing by java and openssl does not match

Tags: java, openssl, rsa, bouncycastle, sign

Please, what am I doing bad that the result of the following java and bash does not match?

Here is the [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647165/how-to-sign-a-generic-text-with-rsa-key-and-encode-with-base64-in-java). I was able to easily write the java (which is actually discussed there), but nobody was concerned about the results. To me, simply, both results are different.

Here is a part of java I use (pem file is without password):

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pemPath)));
Object object = pemParser.readObject();

JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter();
KeyPair kp = converter.getKeyPair((PEMKeyPair) object);
PrivateKey privateKey = kp.getPrivate();

Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("RSA");
sig.initSign(privateKey);
sig.update(stringToSign.getBytes());

byte[] bytes = sig.sign();
return new String(Base64.encode(bytes)); //+ close pemParser
```

Bash code is:

```
printf $(printf "${string_to_sign}" | openssl rsautl -sign -inkey "${pem_path}" | openssl enc -base64 | awk '{printf "%s", $0}' )
```

Comment: Have you tried `"SHA1withRSA"` instead of just `"RSA"`? RSA in itself is not a signature algorithm (or an insecure, rudimentary one at best). In general it is also required to specific a padding mode (PKCS#1 v1.5 in `"SHA1withRSA"`) and hashing algorithm.

Comment: thanks for the comment, but the result using either `"RSA"` or `"SHA1WithRSA"`is the same - and still different comparing to openssl. :-(

Comment: I am taking my comment back!!! I changed the principle of signing and now I use `"RSA/None/PKCS1Padding"` padding with `javax.crypto.Cipher` and it finally works!!! Thanks a lot for this kick!

Comment: I'll take a look at it, but in general you should not (have to) use `Cipher` for signing. It's definitely implementation dependent as the padding is different for signing and encryption - it may however also switch on the type of key being used.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late but if i read http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/rsautl.html

> rsautl because it uses the RSA algorithm directly can only be used to sign or verify small pieces of data.

So it does a raw signature without a digest so I think you should use `NONEwithRSA` (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html)