# Maven plugin signing a specific file

Tags: java, maven, security, build, sign

Let's say I have a document A which is written in plaintext. I am looking for a maven plugin which would (during application clean install) sign it (using RSA key pair) and put the newly created A.signed in the same location as the A file.

I found plugins to sign jar files (jarsigner) and artifacts (gpg:sign), but I am not sure whether there is one for a single non-java file.

Comment: What do you mean by "sign"? And what type of document is it?

Comment: Signing with a private key using a RSA key pair, A is just a plaintext.

Comment: And why "in the same location"? Usually, Maven products are somewhere under `target/`.

Comment: In the same location as the signed file, if A was to be placed in target/documents then A.signed should also be in target/documents

Answer (score 1):

You may write a Java class using code snippets provided here (for example): [How to sign a generic text with RSA key and encode with Base64 in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647165/how-to-sign-a-generic-text-with-rsa-key-and-encode-with-base64-in-java)

and execute it with [Maven Exec Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a look [maven-jarsigner-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jarsigner-plugin/)